# Not able to specify the public variable class

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem with the `var` keyword

I have defined it like this at the form load

```
public partial class form1 :form
{
    public var a;


    private void form1_load(object sender, eventargs e)
    {
        // i have used "a" like this....
        a = abc.members blahhhh blahhhhh
        bindingsource1.datasource = a;
        datagridview1.datasource = bindingsource1;

    }
}
```

but I got the error on this line

> public Var a;

the type or namespace name 'var' could not be defined

Can I define public class varaible so that I can access this all methods in that class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` in C# is different from `var` in other languages; in C# you use `var` to have the compiler determine the type of a certain local variable for you, but you cannot use it to declare fields/properties.

You have to specify the actual type instead. I have no idea what `a` is, so I can't tell you what type to use.

Comment: Then why not just declare it `int a;`?

Comment: no , i want to get the data from linq query ...so the result will be like this..var a = from xyz in aks.members like that...so i want to us esame varaible for thos type of operations...

Comment: Then you can declare your private field as IEnumerable<TheTypeImExpecting>

Comment: @user899271: When you say "use same variable for those type of operations" you do realize that C# is statically typed, right?  `var` isn't the same as `dynamic`.  `var` is used only in in-line code where the type is immediately inferable, but the type is still static.  You can't "declare" a variable as `var`, it's just short-hand for the declaring type when the implementing type is immediately available (in the same statement) for the compiler to infer the type.

Comment: @David: From his use of `var` here in the first place, I don't think he realizes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the concrete type instead of var - for example "string", "int", ...

This is because "var" is only syntactic suggar. The compliler interferes the concrete type and insert it instead of var. In your case this is impossible, because the compiler won't look so far as the form_load - it just looks at the expression after the "="

As a side note: you should not define fields as public. Make them private and define public accessors or public propertys for them. In this way you don't leak internal implementation details to the outside world and got no problems if you want to change this implementation-details later on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it a public (and not a local) variable you have to declare it as a specific type, for example 'string', 'int' or a selfwritten class

Answer (score 0):

variables having an implicit type var must be declared at method scope.

Answer (score 0):

`public int a;` would suffice, i suppose.

As per,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

> Only variables that are declared at method scope can have an implicit type var

As you need this for a linq query, you can assign the explicitly typed public variables wherever (inside a function) you run the query. For example,

```
func()
 {
 var results = from p1 in phones where p1.name="abc";
 MyPublicVariable = results;
 }
```

Where **MyPublicVariable** could be an enumerable.